# How to pass props to components when you use <Route components={} > attribute?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, the `<Route>` component of `react-router` has `components` attribute ([docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#components-1)):

```
<Route path="latest" components={{sidebar: Sidebar, content: ContentLayout}} />
```

Then in an appropriate component I can call those components through component's props:

```
render() {
    <div>
        {this.props.sidebar}
        {this.props.content}
    <div>
}
```

However without `react-router` I would do this, I pass my component custom props:

```
render() {
    <div>
        <Sidebar names={ ['foo', 'bar'] } isOpen={true} num={10} />
        <ContentLayout type={ contentType } background={'#fff'} title={titleOne} />
    <div>
}
```

My questions is. How can I pass props to my component when I use `components` attribute of React Router `<Route>` component?

The best way would be something like this:

```
render() {
    <div>
        {<this.props.sidebar names={ ['foo', 'bar'] } isOpen={true} />}
        {<this.props.content type={ contentType } background={'#fff'} />}
    <div>
}
```

Comment: As Horia said cloning can be a solution, also there can be other solutions too, however generally this approach looks hackish for me, why do you need to pass props there in the first place? if you are using state container like Redux, why don't you just pass props from a container component. Or where props that you are trying to pass coming from?

Comment: @Shota, Do you mean to make use of `connect()` method of `Redux` to pass props from a container? I do so now. But I'd like to eliminate the use of the `connect()`. That's why I want to pass props manually

Comment: The thing is that is also depends on a type of props. if your props that you trying to pass coming from Ajax request they should be be coming from redux. if they are some default options for your components (as I see in your code: isOpen={true}, #fff) more proper place for them would be in constants file, so why don't you externalize them into one constants file and then import them into components wherever you need?

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this is to [clone](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) the components and specify new props for them in the cloning process. Something like:

```
render() {
  return (<div>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.sidebar, props={names: ['foo', 'bar'], isOpen: true})}
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.content, props={type:contentType, background: '#fff'})}
  </div>);
}
```